# Showing data in organized manner from database

Tags: php, database, formatting

I have following piece of code

```
<?php

$connect=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("dbms_teacher",$connect);
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM staffs");
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['fname'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['lname'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" .$row['post']. "</td>";
    echo "<td>". $row['status']. "</td>";

    // echo "<td>". "edit/delete". "</td>";
}
mysql_close($connect);

?>
```

This is the portion of code that brings up data from dbms_teacher. Is there  a way such that I can get the data in a tabular form with fields Name , Post , status ,delete option(which I can manage later) ? I just need a good way to display it in organized format!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're only using select columns, you can hard-code it. It also helps if you get only those columns in your query:

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT fname,lname,post,status FROM staffs");
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr><td>First Name</td><td>Last Name</td><td>Post</td><td>Status</td><td>Edit/Delete</td></tr>";
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['fname'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['lname'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" .$row['post']. "</td>";
    echo "<td>". $row['status']. "</td>";
    echo "<td></td>";
    // echo "<td>". "edit/delete". "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
mysql_close($connect);
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: Thanks! Liked the idea! The solution would have been perfect if you could separate coulumns/rows using lines for a better view.

Comment: That's best either by using `<table border=1>` which will line the table and all cells, or using CSS to specify left/right borders on the td cells.

Answer (score 1):

You must put `echo "<table>";` before your loop and `echo "</table>";` after your loop.

edit:
add some border to table, and list columns names before your loop manually:

```
echo "<table border=1>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><b>fname</b></td><td><b>lname</b></td><td><b>post</b></td><td><b>status</b></td>";
echo "</tr>";
```

Comment: works but , not exaclty the way I would like it to. I want to insert column names as I mentioned in the questions with columns separated by lines. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the markup for table structure like this: see the markup otside the while loop:

```
<?php

$connect=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("dbms_teacher",$connect);
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM staffs");
echo "<table>";
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['fname'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['lname'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" .$row['post']. "</td>";
    echo "<td>". $row['status']. "</td>";

    // echo "<td>". "edit/delete". "</td>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysql_close($connect);

?>
```

Comment: works but , not exactly the way I would like it to. I want to insert column titles as I mentioned in the questions with two columns separated by lines. Thanks though!